# Как проставить в таблице отдельный параметр для потомков (имеющих родителя, но не имеющих своих потомков)

Tags: sql, sql-server

MS SQL Server 2019. Есть таблица имеющая id, name, parent_id

```
id  name      parent_id
__  ____      _________
1   Задача1   null
2   name1     1
3   name2     2
4   Задача2   null
5   name1     4
6   Задача3   null
```

Как рекурсивным запросом определять имеет ли запись потомков или нет и проставлять ей соответствующий параметр (leaf - true - последний элемент не имеющий потомков /false - есть потомки), т.е. получить таблицу следующего вида:

```
id  name      parent_id  leaf
__  ____      _________  ____
1   Задача1   null       false
2   name1     1          false
3   name2     2          true
4   Задача2   null       false
5   name1     4          true
6   Задача3   null       true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем рекурсия? Вьібор всех конечньіх елементов.
       `select id from table  where id not in (select parent_id from table)`

Comment: насколько я понял, этот метод подходит только для верхнего уровня, т.е. в моем случае строку
`id  name   parent_id`
`3  name2  2`
он не определит как последнюю в узле

Comment: прошу прощения, сейчас как надо проверил и действительно, данный запрос выберает все конечные элементы в узлах. Спасибо большое за помощь)